# How should one punctuate a bulleted list in the middle of a sentence, not at the end?

Tags: punctuation

There have been many posts about the proper way to punctuate bulleted lists, but I have not found any that specifically deal with how to punctuate such lists when they appear within a sentence instead of at the end. Example:

"However, individuals who are:

- employed by ABC Inc. on a temporary basis (, ; ?) or
- seconded to ABC Inc. by service providers on a temporary basis (, ; ?)

will not be required to comply with the obligations set out in Section 7 hereunder unless their initial contract is for a period of at leat 3 months on a full-time basis, or unless the position warrants earlier compliance."

In this context, I am not authorized to merge the bullet points into the sentence.

How should this list be punctuated?

Also, is there a name for this kind of list in the middle of a sentence?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you rewrite so the bullets are at the end of the sentence?

Comment: A list in the middle of the sentence is usually referred to as an "inline list" although that's more for lists separated by numerals. A bulleted list like this interrupting the sentence flow strikes me as pretty awkward and perhaps even verges on being stylistically unacceptable. Grammatically, you actually wouldn't need any punctuation there with the "or" though I'm not entirely sure if there's an appropriate overriding style. I would  recommend advising the powers that be to consider rephrasing if possible. You also might want to check the Chicago Manual to see if they have anything on it.

Comment: I'd ignore the bullets and use the same punctuation as I would if these two items were just part of a normal sentence.  In your example, that would mean putting no punctuation marks at the end of either bullet item.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Since I cannot rephrase, I'll simply forego any punctuation as sugggested. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm very late to this question, but in situations where someone has broken out bullet points in the midst of a sentence, and you have no option to reword the sentence or remove the bullet points, I recommend that you punctuate as if the sentence had no bullet points at all.

In the poster's example,

> However, individuals who are:
>
> - employed by ABC Inc. on a temporary basis (, ; ?) or
> - seconded to ABC Inc. by service providers on a temporary basis (, ; ?)
>
> will not be required to comply with the obligations set out in Section 7 hereunder unless their initial contract is for a period of at least 3 months on a full-time basis, or unless the position warrants earlier compliance.

we have what appears to be a beastly long sentence, but if you were to treat it as a single continuous (and unbulleted) sentence, I think you might not see any need to punctuate the phrases that were broken out as bullet points. That is, you might punctuate the sentence as follows:

> However, individuals who are employed by ABC Inc. on a temporary basis or [are] seconded to ABC Inc. by service providers on a temporary basis will not be required to comply with the obligations set out in Section 7 hereunder unless their initial contract is for a period of at least 3 months on a full-time basis, or unless the position warrants earlier compliance.

That being the case, I would be inclined to punctuate the broken-out form of the sentence no more heavily:

> However, individuals who are
>
> - employed by ABC Inc. on a temporary basis or
> - seconded to ABC Inc. by service providers on a temporary basis
>
> will not be required to comply with the obligations set out in Section 7 hereunder unless their initial contract is for a period of at least 3 months on a full-time basis, or unless the position warrants earlier compliance.

The punctuation mark that I would be most tempted to add is a comma after *basis* and before *or* in the first bulleted line, but even there I would try to resist, since logically the *or* doesn't belong in the bulleted item at all but in a separate line:

> However, individuals who are
>
> - employed by ABC Inc. on a temporary basis
>
> or
>
> - seconded to ABC Inc. by service providers on a temporary basis
>
> will not be required to comply with the obligations set out in Section 7 hereunder unless their initial contract is for a period of at least 3 months on a full-time basis, or unless the position warrants earlier compliance.

On balance, I think that giving the *or* a separate line would make the presentation look fussy and silly. The bullets are bad enough when they introduce otherwise unpunctuated text; I wouldn't do anything to make readers dwell even more unnaturally on the broken out language.

---

The *Chicago Manual of Style*, 16th edition (2010) has very little to say on this subject (at **6.125 *Vertical lists punctuated as a sentence***), but it seems to endorse the idea that punctuation should be used only in a way that would continue to make sense if the numbers or bullets of the vertical list disappeared and the list content were run as components of a normal sentence. This is essentially what I've suggested doing above.

Comment: Outdenting (unlisting?) the _or_ also basically defeats the purpose of using a list at all. A list with one item isn't really a list at all.